# strlen() not giving right value?

Tags: c, strlen

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char abc[28] ;
    //abc[26] = '\0';
    abc[0]=65;
    char hj = abc[0];
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
    abc[i]=++hj;

    printf("%d\n",i);

    }
    int l=strlen(abc);
    abc[l]='\0';
    printf("length of abc_array is %d\n",(strlen(abc)));
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(abc); i++)
    {
    printf("%c",abc[i]);
    printf("\n");
    }

}
```

The output length of the string is 39, which is wrong. What is the error?

Comment: `strlen` requires a null. You can't use it to determine where to put the null.

Comment: How is this related to C++? This is clearly a C question.

Comment: Your commented part `//abc[26] = '\0';` was correct, uncomment it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only based on not reading the docs at all.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `abc[i] = '\0'` before you call `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

Standard `strlen` function is only applicable to strings. String is a sequence of characters terminated by zero character. Passing something that is not a string to `strlen` results in undefined behavior.

What you are passing to `strlen` in your code is not a string. This is why you get meaningless results from `strlen`.